# Does 'Torrents time' seed the file you're downloading or have downloaded?

Tags: bittorrent

I'm wondering whether the plug-in 'Torrents time' seeds the file while you're streaming video or if it continues after the video file has been downloaded. Is there a way to check? I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I'm wondering whether the plug-in 'Torrents time' seeds the file while you're streaming?

Torrents Time will upload while you are streaming. See "Does Popcorn Time for web & Torrents Time also upload/seed?" below.

---

#### Does it continues after the video file has been downloaded?

I cannot find any information to say whether it continues to upload after the file is downloaded.

However, given the number of security issues with Torrents Time (see below) you cannot be sure what is happening under the hood when you use this product.

The advice is:

> **As it stands right now, users would be much safer if they avoided installing this application or removed it from their computers until it fixes its security problems**.

Source [Torrents Time Plugin Plagued by Security Issues, Pirate Bay & KAT Users at Risk](http://news.softpedia.com/news/torrents-time-plugin-plagued-by-security-issues-pirate-bay-kat-users-at-risk-500334.shtml)

[My torrents time findings](https://www.reddit.com/r/Piracy/comments/44yl7y/my_torrents_time_findings/) and [Torrents-time Security Issues](http://blog.andrew.im/post/139084882590/torrents-time-security-issues) are also worth reading.

> [image]
>
> Remove this software from your computer, if you put it on your site, remove it, if you think about adding it, don’t.

Source [Torrents-time Security Issues](http://blog.andrew.im/post/139084882590/torrents-time-security-issues)

---

#### Torrents Time Plugin Plagued by Security Issues, Pirate Bay & KAT Users at Risk

...

> The Torrents Time browser plugin that allows users to stream multimedia torrents in real time inside their browser is plagued by various security issues that range from XSS to MitM attacks.

...

> Torrents Time does not properly implement CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing), a crucial Web security mechanism that prevents resources from being loaded from different domains.
>
> This means that an attacker could create a malicious Web page that mimics a regular page (popup) created by TBP or KAT, and add their own malicious code, which, because of an improper CORS implementation, would be allowed to execute.

...

> Torrents Time app was also running as a root user on Mac, which opens a huge security issue for Apple users if an attacker would like to abuse the app and install malware on their machines.

...

> Attackers could also target the server-side files hosted by sites like The Pirate Bay via XSS exploits. The Torrents Time tt.php file runs directly on the main TBP domain, which means attackers could steal cookies if they wanted to.

The Source link includes a reply from Torrents Time.

Source [Torrents Time Plugin Plagued by Security Issues, Pirate Bay & KAT Users at Risk](http://news.softpedia.com/news/torrents-time-plugin-plagued-by-security-issues-pirate-bay-kat-users-at-risk-500334.shtml)

---

#### Does Popcorn Time for web & Torrents Time also upload/seed?

> "Seeding" is a technical term referring specifically to uploading done AFTER a file has been completely downloaded. Whether Popcorn Time
> for web & Torrents Time "seeds" or not it definitely uploads WHILE it
> is downloading. Legally, the distinction would not be significant.
>
> ...
>
> Here is a link to the available options within torrents-time:
> [Torrents Time
> Documentation](https://github.com/torrentsTime/embed/blob/master/docs/options.md)
>
> There is NO OPTION TO NOT UPLOAD.

Source [Does Popcorn Time for web & Torrents Time also upload/seed?](https://pirates-forum.org/Thread-Does-Popcorn-Time-for-web-Torrents-Time-also-upload-seed)